# how to display web page in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry

i have to display web page in my application .

but i m unable to get web page.i m using pushGlobalScreen()  for getting new screen and then i have to display web page

i m using this code

```
BrowserSession site=Browser.getdefaultSession();
site.displayPage(url);
site.showBrowser();
```

pls help me how can i display web page in my application

Answer (score 0):

sudhan, your question isn't very clear. However, if you want to get a webpage from your app, you could take two ways:

1) Invoke web browser and send your application to background. Check this tutorial for more information:

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Invoke_the_browser.html?nodeid=1487366&vernum=0

2) If you're working in OS 5.0 or newer, you can use BrowserField and display the webpage within your application.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Browser_field_1184788_11.jsp